# UIView draw(_ rect: CGRect) doesn't work with multithreading

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, charts

```
class GradientChart: LineChartView {

private let accessQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "SynchronizedColor", qos: .userInteractive)
private var color: UIColor?

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    accessQueue.async {
        self.updateColors()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            super.draw(rect)
        }
    }
}

func updateColors() {
    if self.color != nil
        self.dataSet.setColor(self.color!)
        self.dataSet.fillColor = self.color!
        self.color = nil
    }
}

func setColor(_ color: UIColor) {
    accessQueue.async() {
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

LineChartView is class from Charts library

I use serial accessQueue for thread-safe work with LineChartView and color variable. When super.draw(rect) called on DispatchQueue.main I see blank white screen.

I debugged LineChartView's draw() and found that UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() returns nil. Why?

Comment: UIKit expects all drawing to be done by the time `draw` finishes. Async calls mean `draw` will finish before the other async calls. All UI work should be done one the main thread.

Comment: Is this an attempt on animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the current graphics context for this view as a door that automatically opens just before `drawRect` starts to run and closes when it finishes.

Now think about what asynchronous means for the notion “finishes”. We return from the current runloop and the door closes before any asynchronous code can even begin.

So your code works like this:

```
// the door opens
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    accessQueue.async {
        // the door closes
        self.updateColors()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            super.draw(rect)
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as the door closes there is no current graphics context and all drawing commands have nowhere to go. Your entire code is thus useless.

> debugged LineChartView's draw() and found that UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() returns nil. Why?

That’s why. By the time that code runs there is no graphics context any longer.

Answer (score 1):

UIKit expects all drawing to be done on the main thread.  If you want to draw in the background you need to use Core graphics at the CALayer level instead.  See the documentation for [CALayer.drawsAsynchronously](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410974-drawsasynchronously)